# Mocking API call in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I need to mock API calls for a button click but the actual call is nested down in a utility file that is called by a middleware file.  Some framework code was using Jest, axios-mock-adapter, and Enzyme.  (I'm still wrapping my head around what each of these do).

So let me preface this.  I'm an intern at a company where my task is to test some JS code for a piece of software built on a microservice architecture.  So first let me apologize for any improper verbage.  My background is in C/C++ and x86 assembly.  No, I didn't fudge my resume when applying for this position.  The company was fully aware that I had little to no experience with JS.  I've attempted to create a mock = MockAdapter('axios') then calling that with mock.OnGet().reply() but when checking my coverage it seems to error every time.

Theres to much code to post so I'll try to give an example

```
class ComponentName extends component {
    stuff
}

ComponentNameFunc {
    this.middleware.funcName.then(
        response ()=>{}
        errorRespone ()={}
    )
}


//funcName is a name of a middleware function that calls a function 
//in the utility file.  The utility file does the axios.get call
```

When I render the component then simulate a button click it calls this.middleware.funcName but then the coverage shows it going to the errorResponse portion.  Heres a test example

```
describe('test',()=>{
    test('button click', done => {
        mock.onGet('aURL').reply(200,mockData);
        Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <ComponentName/>);
        expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
        wrapper
            .find("Button")
            .at(0)
            .simulate("click");
        done();
    )};
 )};
```

EDIT: So I found part of the issue.  I had multiple mocks for different API calls and apparently only 1 was registering.  However, some of these functions that I'm testing will make two API calls.  How do I mock up two separate API calls for a single test?  Originally I had some thing like this

```
import axios from "axios"
let mock = MockAdapter(axios);
let mock2 = MockAdapter(axios);


mock.OnGet("URL").reply(200,Data);
mock2.OnGet("URL2").reply(200,DifferentData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.  I was trying to make multiple mock variables (or are they objects?) like mock, mock2, mock3.  It seems replicating mock.OnGet.reply with different information works just fine.